# jQuery - trigger event when "unhover" on elements for a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing some default animations that will only be triggered when none of the 4 buttons are being hovered for 1 second. 
The timer should reset if any of the buttons are hovered during the waiting period (i.e. that 1 second). Any idea? Thanks!

[UPDATE]
See my snippets in below comment, hope someone find it useful.

Comment: What have you got/tried? We're helpful, but we're not psychic.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/monkichik/wAUBQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var timer;

    function schedule() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            // start timer
        }, 1000);
    };

    $('button').hover(function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, function() {
        schedule();
    });
    schedule();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GysxK/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of the button has a class 'btn'

```
$(".btn").bind('onmouseenter',function(){
//Clear the Timer
   window.clearInterval();

//count the timer and write the logic
   window.setInterval(function(){
   //Logic of Animation you are gonna do if no hovering happens in 1 sec
},1000);
});
```